# Could not select proper Transport Descriptor in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Here code of my project. I use direct Tcp connection But i get "Could not select proper Transport Descriptor" error.

```
 BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();


myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGAION_MODE_POINTER);
    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);


    add(browserField);
    browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.co.in;deviceside=true");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find another thread about it [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blackberry-JDE-5-0-BroswerField2-throws-error/m-p/469942#M94260); if it's on the simulator, tweaking your dns settings might help.

Answer (score 0):

Some times  "Could not select proper Transport Descriptor" error may occur because of missing slash in web link.Add slashes if you did not add slashes in your link.

Might be the problem will solve.If your link like

https://geniuscloud.net/mobileapp/api/view1 change it to

https://geniuscloud.net/mobileapp/api/view/1

Comment: ok,another situation above error will occur is,if u stopped ur mobile ntwork connection start it.using manage connections

Comment: koti, you r not getting my point when i append interface= wifi in URl then its works fine  but i want to make connection that also work with mobile provider connection i.e 3G,edge n/w.

Comment: ok please tell whether your mobile network connection checked or unchecked  go through  MobileConnections->Mobile Network.